# I have finished vs I have already finished

Tags: word-usage

what's the difference between "I have finished" and "I have already finished"?
do we need to use "already"?

Comment: "Will you finish that task soon?" "Oh, I've already finished it." You only need to use _already_ if you want to emphasise that something happened some time before now.

Comment: *I have finished* would usually be uttered *immediately after* finishing, but (emphatic) *I have **already** finished* wouldn't normally occur until some time after finishing - often, *specifically as a contradictory response* to something implying that I might *not have **yet** finished*. In rare circumstances, an over-eager exam-taker might leap up and say *I have already finished*, half-an-hour into an exam for which an hour is allowed. But even that would really be by way of "contradicting" the unspoken idea that she might need longer. It's a kind of negating ***rebuttal*** statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"I have finished"** is indicating that you have done a specific task. While **"I have already finished"** means that you already finished but the sentence is more direct since you used *already.*

- When used with the present perfect, it implies "before now." We use *already* to emphasize that something happened before something else, or that something happened sooner than planned. Although in some cases using *already* can be identified as rude behaviour.